# How to map data in react on Radio button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, radio-button, mapping

Iam trying to display data in react js. Whenever user selects a radio button the data in the api should be displayed according to option selected by the user. i have mapped my radio button component. now i want it to display data according to selected option. the value coming rom the api is mapped below and i have commented on the section where i want to display my text.the parameter is reward_description which is to be mapped.

My code is below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  ModalComponent,
  GiftCardComp,
  RadioInputComponent,
} from "../../../components/index";
import IntlMessages from "../../../common/constants/IntlMessages";

export default class Comp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      giftCard: "",
      giftDescription: ""
    };
  }
  render() {
        let {giftDescription} = this.state
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ModalComponent
          isOpen={this.props.isOpenPayment}
          toggle={this.props.paymenToggle}
          className="customModel"
          size="lg"
          body={
            <React.Fragment>
              <div className="modal-col">
                <div className="product-box">
                  <div className="product-img">
                    <a href="#">
                      <img
                        src={this.props.giftDetails.desktop_image}
                        alt="product-name"
                      />
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div className="product-description">
                    <div className="product-description-text">
                      <h3 className="mx-auto">
                        <a href="#">{this.props.giftDetails.heading}</a>{" "}
                      </h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <GiftCardComp
                    information={null}
                    description={
                      <React.Fragment>
                       
                    sideBarHtml={
                      <React.Fragment>
                        <h3><IntlMessages id="gift.radio-heading" /></h3>

                        <RadioInputComponent
                          title="giftCard"
                          value={this.state.giftCard}
                          name={this.props.giftDetails.variations.map(
                            (e) => e.reward_text
                          )}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            this.setState({ giftCard: e.target.value });
                          }}
                          onClick={(e) => {
                            this.setState({ giftDescription: e.target.value });
                          }}
                        />
                         <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: giftDescription}}/>
                        <hr />
                        
                      </React.Fragment>
                    }
                  </React.Fragment>
                </div>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          }
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

My API Response
```

"variations": [
{
"variation_id": 1,
"variation_name": "210kr",
"price": "210",
"reward_text": "200kr. Price",
"reward_description": "Med et gavekort til Sendentanke.dk kan du vælge mellem gavekort til hundredevis af butikker og oplevelser ét sted.Med et gavekort til Sendentanke.dk kan du vælge mellem gavekort til hundredevis af butikker og oplevelser ét sted.Med et gavekort til Sendentanke.dk kan du vælge mellem gavekort til hundredevis af butikker og oplevelser ét sted.Med et gavekort til Sendentanke.dk kan du vælge mellem gavekort til hundredevis af butikker og oplevelser ét sted."
},
{
"variation_id": 2,
"variation_name": "400kro",
"price": "400",
"reward_text": "400 Price",
"reward_description": "Med et gavekort til Sendentanke.dk kan du vælge mellem gavekort til hundredevis af butikker og oplevelser ét sted."
}
],

Comment: do you try to take the value of the radio you pick and then do ternary operator or if else (your choice) and then bu the value render what you need

Comment: can you please show me how it is to be done

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created header a small component that showcase what I talked about here you have no value and when you start to pick it had the component.
if you want to start with someone checked add `checked` and in the state add his value

```
const Radios = () => {
      const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="huey"
              name="drone"
              value="huey"
              onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label for="huey">Huey</label>
          </div>
    
          <div>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="dewey"
              name="drone"
              value="dewey"
              onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
          </div>
    
          <div>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="louie"
              name="drone"
              value="louie"
              onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label for="louie">Louie</label>
          </div>
    
          {value === "huey" ? (
            <h1>Huey</h1>
          ) : value === "dewey" ? (
            <h1>Dewey</h1>
          ) : value === "louie" ? (
            <h1>Louie</h1>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      );
    };
```